# How to make Local Notification in android?

Tags: android

```
public class ChildLock extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int increment;
    int maximum ;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
     EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        // get the maximum value
        EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
        // convert the text value to a integer
          maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        // display the progressbar
        dialog.show();

        // create a thread for updating the progress bar
        Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
           public void run() 
           {
               try 
               {
                     while(dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()) 
                   {
                       // wait 500ms between each update
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                       // active the update handler
                       progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                   }
            }
               catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) 
               {
                   // if something fails do something smart
               }
           }
        });
        background.start();
    }

    // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            if(dialog.getProgress()== dialog.getMax())
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildLock.this, notifi.class);
                   startActivity(i);

            }
            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        }

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your progress bar in a thread which generally happen as below
then you have to pass message to UI thread from this thread

```
     public class MyActivity extends Activity {
             private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

             private ProgressBar mProgress;
             private int mProgressStatus = 0;

         private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

         protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
             super.onCreate(icicle);

             setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

             mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

             // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                         mProgressStatus = doWork();
                          mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                        }
                        //pass messege to UI thread
                         Message msg=new Message();
                         msg.obj="your text";
                         mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                         });
                     }
                 }
             }).start();
         }
     }
```

and your mHandler will be like this for notification

```
mHandler = new Handler() { 
              @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
                 String i=(String)msg.obj;
                 Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          };
```

paste this code after 
your while loop of progressbar thread

```
while(dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()){
   .......... 
  }

Message msg=new Message();
msg.obj="your text";
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

and create mHandler at onCreate() method

Comment: @sunil i have edited my Q. to my Progress Bar code..please see and help me to integrate your idea there...Thanks in Advance

Comment: @sunil should i write new class for notification message box or simply write the code in progress handler...???

Comment: no you don't need to write a class. toast will do exactly what you want

Comment: can i put a button on toast message box???because i want to put that buttons on message box..So,how to achieve it...?and once i got message box user must not able to go anywhere...

Comment: then you should go for alert dialog see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: @Sunil i have created dialog but it occures in my application only as i want that message box on any current running application....so how to achieve it??

Comment: search custom dialog in above link

Comment: well if you want to put button in toast then you can using custom toast http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html. plz accept answer if you find it useful